# Custom component for JList instead of just strings

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to freshen up on my Java knowledge and I've been building a small GUI program and I've been running into a bit of a problem.

Basically, I have a `JList` which I'm currently populating with strings from an object from one of my classes which implement `AbstractListModel` which we can call my `ItemList` class. It contains an `ArrayList` of objects of the type `Item` which implements `Serializable`.

But, what I'd like to do is rather than populate my `JList` with a bunch of strings I'd like to populate it with some kind of string + `JTextField` combination so I can see one property of each `Item` object while also being able to update another property by changing the `JTextField`.

Now, what I'm looking for is the simplest possible way of doing this, and I am assuming there is a (relatively) simple way to do this since it's such a common thing to want to do in a GUI application (although I wouldn't put it past Java and Swing to make it convoluted and complicated).

So, what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: It sounds as if you want to use a JTable, not a JList.

Comment: Maybe. But still, a ``JTable`` is for tables of data. I've got a list of objects and I want to display two properties and make one of them editable. Down the road there are a few other things I'd like to do as well which make me thing a list of objects makes a lot more sense than a table. Or to put it another way, it just makes more sense to have each "row" be an item which references an ``Item`` object since this isn't really tabular data.

Comment: I don't agree. A JTable and a JList are for *displaying objects as rows*. In a JTable you can more readily display two or more properties of the object, and you can select columns to be editable or not.

Comment: Yes, that is true. However, down the road I am looking to do actual layout within each list element (and not just display properties side-by-side). Right now step one is simply to be able to display something beyond a string (or an object's ``toString()`` output).

Comment: To display more than a String, you would need to create a custom cell renderer, and the JList tutorial will show you how to do that.

Comment: Use Cell renderer extening from a component like JPanel, so each item in JList will be a JPanel with your custom components like JLabels and JTextFields

Comment: Ah, implementing ``ListCellRenderer`` while extending ``JPanel`` or some other container class seems to be the key. I suspected it was something like that, I just haven't touched Java or any of the related APIs for years...

Comment: JList doesn't support editing ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to ever use `String` objects.  Instead:

- Put `Item` objects in the `JList`.
- Add a `ListCellRenderer` to the list, to show the `Item` object the most user friendly way.
- When the user selects an item, show the details in a **different place** (I'm thinking a panel with 2 columns of labels and text fields, and two rows - one for each attribute, and perhaps a button to <kbd>Save</kbd>)

The edit controls would best be encapsulated in a panel that can then hidden when not required, & put in a variety of places, e.g.

- Below the list
- In the main part of the GUI
- displayed in a `JOptionPane` or a (modal or not) `JDialog`

Here is an [example of placing the 'view/edit panel' (the file details) below the selection component (the table)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

[image]