# Change the label of JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, file, label, jcombobox

I am passing the array of `File` Class to the `JComboBox`. So that it is displaying me whole path of selected file in GUI. I want to display only file name in the combo box.

Code is as follows:

```
public void generateGui(File[] files){

    // main frame
    frame = new JFrame("All In One");
    frame.setSize(500, 300);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            JPanel scriptPanel = new JPanel();

JCombobox scriptList = new JComboBox(files); // Passing the array of File class

    scriptPanel.add(scriptList);
            frame.add(scriptPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1) *"in JAVA"*  It is spelled 'Java' And there is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) to display just the file name.  Though given they are files, you might want to display the icon as well, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11705874/418556)

[image]

Also see the `FileListCellRenderer` of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336902/418556).

[image]

Comment: *"can I get the code structure for that ?"*  By 'code structure' DYM code?

Comment: Did you read the edit?  There is an example in **`FileListCellRenderer`**!